# group by over three elements to display all possible combinations

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have three tables as following and I try to group by over three elements to display all possible combinations

```
Play
--------------------------------
id    typeId    periodId
--------------------------------
1     a       1         
2     b       1         
3     b       1         
4     b       1         
5     a       2         
6     b       1         
7     a       1         
8     b       2         


Period
-------------
periodId
-------------
1
2
3


Type
-------------
typeId
-------------
a
b
c
```

I tried this but it doesn't work, I see some NULL values but the group by doesn't work.

```
SELECT type, p, count(*) as superNiceCount
FROM Play 
RIGHT JOIN Period pp ON Play.periodId = Period.periodId
RIGHT JOIN Type tt ON Play.typeId = Type.typeId
GROUP BY tt.typeId, pp.periodId
```

The expected result would be

```
-------------------------
type p  superNiceCount
-------------------------
a   1    2 
a   2    1
a   3    0
b   1    4
b   2    1
b   3    0
c   1    0
c   2    0
c   3    0
```

How may I achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see if this works

```
SELECT ty.typeId as type, pe.periodId as p, count(pl.id) as superNiceCount
FROM Period pe 
CROSS JOIN Type ty 
LEFT JOIN Play pl ON (pl.periodId = pe.periodId AND pl.typeId = ty.typeId)
GROUP BY ty.typeId, pe.periodId
```

if not try

```
SELECT ty.typeId as type, pe.periodId as p, count(pl.id) as superNiceCount
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM
    Period pe 
    CROSS JOIN Type ty 
) as t1
LEFT JOIN Play pl ON (pl.periodId = t1.periodId AND pl.typeId = t1.typeId)
GROUP BY ty.typeId, pe.periodId
```

Comment: Thanks ! But they both output the same result, which is not good unfortunately

Comment: ah danit, didn't had a machine to test it with at that time. I've updated the SQL and it should work now.

Comment: awesome I didn't know the CROS JOIN operator !